# Prevent unmount of component if validation errors exist on form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, formik

I've seen this done on a few different websites, but unsure how best to go about this in React.

I have a form, that has some validation but I want to prevent a user from redirecting to another route of the form has validation errors.

#### FormComponent.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import TextInput from "./TextInput";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const FormComponent = () => {
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState();

  const formRef = useRef(null);

  const onFormSubmit = async (values) => {
    console.log({ values });
  };

  const validationSchema = () => {
    const schema = {
      test: Yup.string().required("Input is Required")
    };
    return Yup.object(schema);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setInitialValues({
      test: ""
    });
  }, []);

  const validateForm = async () => {
    if (initialValues && formRef?.current?.validateForm) {
      const errors = await formRef.current.validateForm();
      if (errors && Object.keys(errors).length !== 0) console.log(errors);
      else console.log("continue with redirection");
    }
  };

  return initialValues ? (
    <Form
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={onFormSubmit}
      formRef={formRef}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
    >
      <TextInput name="test" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  ) : null;
};

export default FormComponent;
```

I have a function `validateForm` that would need to be called when a user tries to navigate away from the route. (the console logs dictating what needs to be done, either prevent navigating to new route or stay on current route).

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-kowalevski-z2hc1?file=/src/FormComponent.js) with the above example.

No idea how to go about this.

I did come across `routerWillLeave` in `react-router` for only seemingly classed based components, however, I am using `react-router-dom` and function based components.

I am also aware of the `Prompt` component in `react-router-dom` and

1. I am not sure how to only trigger this on unmount
2. It has the option to continue redirect when I can't allow that if there are validation errors

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I looked at the CodeSandbox but I'm not sure that I understand the use case.  You want to **require** that the user submits a valid input before clicking on "Other Page"?  They can't just abandon the form and look at the other page?  Why not?  It seems like "Other Page" is a top-level page on the site and it is always visible in navigation on every page, correct?

Comment: I would handle this by using a `useLocation` hook to not show the `Navigation` component at all if we are on the form page.

Comment: This was just an example. The actual webapp is more like a wizard. They can access the homepage but every other page relies on the data that is submitted on a form so need to restrict users to just the homepage and this form unless that data is present.

Answer (score 1):

You could conditionally disable all links, but to prevent url change - you'd have to point all the routes to the form location conditionally... But still you'd have to store the form data within `localStorage` to make it persistent during the routes' change. The same applies to a page refresh. Then, on valid submit, you'd clear the `localStorage`, enable the links and restore all the routes. But donyou really think it's worth it? Or maybe a `sessionStorage` is more appropriate, not to enforce the user to stay stuck in this form forever...

Comment: That could potentially work. There is one URL that can be accessed, essentially a homescreen,  but the purpose is that they are stuck on that form until they complete, every other route is dependent on the information that comes from this form.

Comment: So how about a +1 :)